# How to change private S3 bucket setting to serve images as http (not https) with django-storages?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

I am using boto with django-storages to upload images directly to S3 from my django form. Everything is ok, except image url is https. I think having https is overkill and not required for media files. How do I change the setting to serve images as http? Went through documentation, couldn't find right settings.

My AWS setting is as follows.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'xxx'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'private'
AWS_LOCATION = '/media/'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I read the django-storages source code, and it's there.

[django-storages on github](https://github.com/iserko/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/s3boto.py)

All I need to do is set SECURE_URLS to false, like this.

```
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
```

:)